# Why is flash resizing my images?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, scaling, resize

O.K I'm really confused about some resizing behaviour in flex and I'm hoping somebody can explain whats going on to me.

I have a container movieclip 3 movieclips deep.

MC2 is inside MC1 and MC3 is inside MC2.

I have another movieclip that contains a bimap image that is 55 pixels wide and 38 pixels high.

When I add this movieclip to MC3 the movieclip becomes 55 pixels wide and "48" pixels high.

Why is this happening and how can I maintain the original desired size?

Comment: How does this question relate to Flex?

Comment: Because I'm developing with flex maybe?

I havnt being doing flex too long so there may nuances related to scaling, movieclips etc different from flash that I'm not aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your whole stage is being resized
- Somewhere you set the height of MC1, MC2 or MC3 and this changed the scaleY
- Or you set the scaleY value yourself

Use a simple trace(MCx.scaleY) to find where is the issue.

Comment: Thankyou!

I hunted down the culprit, I had transformed MC3 in the flash IDE and totally forgotten about it.

I'm really glad to have gotten this sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the *scaleMode* of the *Stage* of your application.

Here's a related article: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Stage.html

Comment: Hi,
thanks for trying to help.

I've tried every possible scale mode and the undesirible scaling is still happening.

I'm baffled